# How to extract randomically elements from a dictionary considerating a value's attribute in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, random

I want to extract, randomically, an element from a dictionary considering the frequency value: I want the output to be one of the highest frequency value everytime BUT it's not excluded that an element with low frequency value is extracted.

Like, if I have
*"x": 4.5, "y": 7.1, "z": 9.3, "w": 1.2, "k": 5.8, "p": 2.3*

I want my output to be often *"z"*, *"y"*, sometimes *"x"*, *"k"* and seldom *"w"*,*"p"* (hope this makes sense)

```
{Kitchen_Activity : {'near the bathroom sink': {'frequency': 0, 'average duration': 0, 'standard deviation': 0}, 'near the fridge': {'frequency': 0.2631578947368421, 'average duration': Timedelta('0 days 00:00:08.200000'), 'standard deviation': Timedelta('0 days 00:00:08.288546314')}, 'near the stove': {'frequency': 0.2631578947368421, 'average duration': Timedelta('0 days 00:00:04.200000'), 'standard deviation': Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.836660026')}, 'on the bed': {'frequency': 0, 'average duration': 0, 'standard deviation': 0}, 'near the shower': {'frequency': 0, 'average duration': 0, 'standard deviation': 0}, 'at the kitchen entrance from the hallway': {'frequency': 0.10526315789473684, 'average duration': Timedelta('0 days 00:00:05'), 'standard deviation': Timedelta('0 days 00:00:01.414213562')}, 'at the bedroom entrance': {'frequency': 0, 'average duration': 0, 'standard deviation': 0}}
Read: {...}
Sleep: {...}
}
```

In this snippet of my dictionary, I have some elements with `frequency = 0` and some with a specific value. Is there a way to extract, randomically, one of this element like `'near the fridge'` considering the frequency?

I tried using `random.choices()` but I think I'm not using it correctly because I get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'Timedelta'` and others errors. Thanks!

Comment: The function `choices()` has a parameter `weights`, have you looked at it ?

Comment: @Aymen yes but I think I didn't understand how to use it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

kitchen_activity =  {'near the bathroom sink':{'frequency': 0, 'average duration': 0, 'standard deviation': 0},
                    'near the fridge': {'frequency': 0.2631578947368421}, 
                    'near the stove': {'frequency': 0.2631578947368421},
                    'on the bed': {'frequency': 0, 'average duration': 0, 'standard deviation': 0},
                    'near the shower': {'frequency': 0, 'average duration': 0, 'standard deviation': 0},
                    'at the kitchen entrance from the hallway': {'frequency': 0.10526315789473684},
                    'at the bedroom entrance': {'frequency': 0, 'average duration': 0, 'standard deviation': 0}}


keys = [] #list for keys
freq = [] #list for frequencies
for k,v in kitchen_activity.items():
    keys.append(k)
    freq.append(v['frequency']) 

freq = [f/sum(freq) for f in freq] #normalize the frequency
    
print(np.random.choice(keys, 100, p=freq))
```